# Add line break between buttons generated in react loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I a trying to add a line break after a button that is generated in a react loop. I've tried adding  elements but that has not worked:

```
<div className="connect-container"> 
  <div>
  {connectors.map((connector) => (
    <button className="metamask-button"
      disabled={!connector.ready}
      key={connector.id}
      onClick={() => connect(connector)}
    >
      {connector.name}
      {!connector.ready && ' (unsupported)'}
      {isConnecting &&
        connector.id === pendingConnector?.id &&
        ' > > >'}
    </button> 
  )) }  
</div>
```

There should be a space between the buttons. Currently they are stacked without spacing.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach worked, but only by adding margin-bottom:

```
.connect-container button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using following CSS

```
.connect-container button {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   float: none;
}
```

Another simple & easy way using flex-box.

```
.connect-container>div{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column
}
```

Code example

```css
.connect-container button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="connect-container"> 
  <div>
 
    <button className="metamask-button" > Button 1 </button> 
    
    <button className="metamask-button" > Button 2 </button> 

</div>
```

Example 2:

```css
.connect-container>div{
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
<div class="connect-container"> 
  <div>
 
    <button className="metamask-button" > Button 1 </button> 
    
    <button className="metamask-button" > Button 2 </button> 

</div>
```

Comment: Another way is to add `<br/>` tag after `</button>` but it is not recommended  .

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these approaches worked, the buttons are still stacked without spacing. I need to persist the "loop" structure. In the code snippets provided there are no spaces between buttons

Comment: Css may overriding by other CSS properties who have high priority over the css i have provided.  Try using !important after CSS properties. especially after display:flex  .. Try using chrome inspector-> Computed to see what CSS properties these buttons have.